# How do i fix "Subscript indices must either be real positive"?

Tags: matlab

So I'm trying to make a .m file that calculates the fourier-series and plots it, but I keep getting an error

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

I have located where the code error is located, but i have no idea how to fix this, can you help me understand this error?

The error happens when I try to sum my function so in `sum(a0)`.

My code:

```
syms k x

f = [... 
    cos(x)
    ];  

a = [... % Hele perioden 
    -pi pi;
    ]; 



sum = [2 5 20]; % N - Antal af Fourie-skridt. 

%% Fourie Koeffiecienter 
for i = 1:length(f)
    a0(i) =  int(f(i),x,a(i,:)); %a_0 findes 
    ak(i) =  int(f(i)*cos(k*pi*x/max(a(:))),x,a(i,:))  ; %a_k findes
    bk(i) =  int(f(i)*sin(k*pi*x/max(a(:))),x,a(i,:)) ; %b_k findes
end 

a0 = 1/(2*max(a(:))) * sum(a0);
ak = 1/(max(a(:))) * sum(ak);
bk = 1/(max(a(:))) * sum(bk);


%% Summen for 3 forskellige N
x = linspace(a(1,1),max(a(:)),25); %linspace til x for hele perioden.


fsum_1 = a0 + symsum(ak*cos(k*pi*x/max(a(:))) + bk*sin(k*pi*x/max(a(:))),k,1,sum(1,1));
fsum_2 = a0 + symsum(ak*cos(k*pi*x/max(a(:))) + bk*sin(k*pi*x/max(a(:))),k,1,sum(1,2));
fsum_3 = a0 + symsum(ak*cos(k*pi*x/max(a(:))) + bk*sin(k*pi*x/max(a(:))),k,1,sum(1,3));%F.R sum  


%% plot 
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(x,fsum_1)
title(['Fourierække ved n =',num2str(sum(1,1))])

subplot(3,1,2)
plot(x,fsum_2)
title(['Fourierække ved n =',num2str(sum(1,2))])

subplot(3,1,3)
plot(x,fsum_3)
title(['Fourierække ved n =',num2str(sum(1,3))])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have used `sum` as a variable. By doing this you're overloading the builtin function `sum()`. Thus, when you try to do: `sum(a0)`, MATLAB tries to use `a0` as an index to the vector `sum` which obviously fails. You *could* [workaround this](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html), but I would not recommend it as it's easy to forget that you did it when you're working with the code in a week/month/year from now.

MATLAB has a lot of builtin function, most of which have very intuitive names. `sum, max, min, length, size, abs, ...` [the list goes on](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/functionlist.html). Try to avoid using such names as variable names as that can easily mess up your code. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287856/how-can-i-write-protect-the-matlab-language#comment52453509_32287856), I think you'll find it interesting.

Also, using [`i` and `j` as variable names in MATLAB is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) (although you probably learnt it in MATLAB 101).

The good thing about programming is, you're rarely the first one to have [encountered the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20Subscript%20indices%20must%20either%20be%20real%20positive%20integers%20or%20logicals). There are 147 questions with the exact same error message posted on SO. You can have a look at Dennis' [generic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol), or any of [t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22197457/2338750)[h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22364921/2338750)[e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21105579/2338750)[s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14475397/2338750)[e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15339331/2338750)   ( <= The letters are links.)

Comment: Good answer. MATLAB really should not allow overwriting of built-in functions, that'd save approximately 147 questions on SO :)

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan! I bet it's a lot more than 147! Not everyone manages to put the error message in the question. And, I actually don't agree with you. You will suddenly have a lot of worthless code the moment Mathworks decides to create a few functions. `my_sum`, `abs_val`, `res`, `results` +++. A warning in the editor would be nice though =)

Comment: Hmm, they could ban it and show the same kind of warning as is currently on functions that "will be removed in a future release". Warning would be good anyway for sure.